# Manage.py permission error

Tags: linux, permissions, python, nginx

Here is my static and media files configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/var/www/static/',
]
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/pia.com/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

when I try to run the command `python manage.py collectstatic` I get `Permission Denied`: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/pia.com/static/admin'`
Could you help me to figure out why this occurs.
Thank tou for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because most likely the file (or directory) `/var/www/pia.com/static/admin` needs root permissions to access. Thus you need to run python as superuser:

```
sudo python manage.py collectstatic
```

or check that file's permissions and change them so you can write/read there.

Here is a guide: [File permissions and attributes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)

Comment: I tried it but it says sudo: python: command not found

Comment: How exactly and where did you run it? It seems impossible for you to receive that error just because you run it as a superuser.

Comment: I ran it in /home/tudor/PiaBlog (my website directory)